How to install github copilot plugin in eclipse
I need assistance in installing github copilot plugin in eclipse to use copilot for automation of rest assured api project
Details below :
I tried two ways to install plugin in eclipse IDE Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)

By Directly installing plugin from eclipse market place by specifying it has github copilot as shown in image

and we got following error


Installing using unofficial website - https://vgcpge.github.io/eclipse.copilot/ specified in video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_QZao3abBw but it din't install copilot but showed it would install source rather as shown in image




The "more info" says you need a newer version of Eclipse. You also seem to have network proxy problems blocking access to required sites.

I tried with latest version of eclipse as well but same issue is seen

Part of your problem is as suggested by greg-449 in his comment. https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/copilot4eclipse mentions that supported Eclipse versions are (currently) :
Eclipse Versions: 2024-06 (4.32), 2024-03 (4.31), 2023-12 (4.30), 2023-09 (4.29), 2023-06 (4.28), 2024-06 (4.33)
